# Can a shiny Ditto turn into shiny versions of other Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-series

I am DexNav chaining to get a shiny Ditto and I am wondering will it change into shiny Pokemon?

Answer (score 21):

Past Generation 4 (Diamond/Pearl/Platinum), whether Ditto is shiny or not, a Ditto will transform into the coloration of its opponent.

If the opponent is shiny, shiny Ditto will Transform into shiny. If the opponent is not shiny, shiny Ditto will Transform into normal coloration.

Comment: And therefor non-shiny ditto will transform to shiny opponent?

Comment: @Mathias711 The user of Transform copies the target's coloration and form, so yes, if the opponent is shiny, Ditto will turn into a shiny copy.

Comment: What about games prior to Diamond/Pearl/Platinum?

Answer (score 0):

Ditto takes the other pokémon appearance; if the other pokémon is shiny, it will become shiny, if not, it will remain "normal". A shiny Ditto doesn't chance anything, as you can see [here](http://youtu.be/m9rpDZ9e7cQ)